# Excel crashes when I try access Access DB

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2013, ms-access-2016

Symptoms:

When I my code runs the following code Excel abruptly closes.

```
Private Sub OpenConnection()

   If Not (DBCon.State And adStateOpen) = adStateOpen Then DBCon.Open "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; data source=C:\Users\bissonp\Desktop\ai\ai2.accdb;"

End Sub
```

References in  Excel VBA are as follows

> Visual Basic For Applications
>
> Microsoft Excel 15.0 Object Library
>
> OLE Automation
>
> Microsoft Office 15.0 Object Library
>
> Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library
>
> Microsoft Scripting Runtime
>
> Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library

Both Excel and Access are 64-Bit

I have run this program on a computer with MS Excel and Access 2016 and it works. Any suggestions as to how to solve Excel crashing. Thanks.

Edit: Using Event viewer as suggested in the comments I have the following errors

```
Faulting application name: EXCEL.EXE, version: 15.0.5045.1000, time stamp: 0x5b0d303b
Faulting module name: mso.dll, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x5b1fa456
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00000000005b0e04
Faulting process id: 0x4f00
Faulting application start time: 0x01d4305c562934ce
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Root\Office15\EXCEL.EXE
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Office15\mso.dll
Report Id: 7450046f-8670-463f-b15f-48faccf15016
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

AND

```
Fault bucket 1277345556296028794, type 4
Event Name: APPCRASH
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: EXCEL.EXE
P2: 15.0.5045.1000
P3: 5b0d303b
P4: mso.dll
P5: 0.0.0.0
P6: 5b1fa456
P7: c0000005
P8: 00000000005b0e04
P9: 
P10: 

Attached files:
\\?\C:\Users\pasca\AppData\Local\Temp\1828426875.cvr
\\?\C:\Users\pasca\OneDrive\Desktop\ai\ai2.xlsm
\\?\C:\Users\pasca\AppData\Local\Temp\CVR6E26.tmp.cvr
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER9584.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER95A4.tmp.xml
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER95C3.tmp.csv
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER95E3.tmp.txt

These files may be available here:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_EXCEL.EXE_274d175a8bce6eaa415e2ad0764c80f2fd668880_00000000_748b9a18

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: 7450046f-8670-463f-b15f-48faccf15016
Report Status: 2147487744
Hashed bucket: 2c96ba3a635c42dce1ba0b040a72d27a
Cab Guid: 0
```

Comment: sounds like prank behavior. do you have any "friends" in the office?  i can't help much more than that but explaining how it's closing might give someone the info they need to identify the problem.  is it acontrolled exit, do termination events fire, does it crash, are there logs or messages?

Comment: The version that worked was from work computers while the one that "crashes" is from my own personal computer. I don't think anyone was playing with my home computer. When I reopen the excel file that closed unexpectedly it opens as "Recovered". Where would I get the logs of excel?

Comment: Also sometimes it just reopens on its own after "crashing".

Comment: event viewer will have crash logs if enabled.  2 different computers?.   please tell me you updated your code for the different environment.

Comment: I've updated the source destination but as I can tell the rest of the code runs smoothly until I need to access the DB. I've pasted the errors I've found in event viewer. Thanks for letting me know of event viewer.

Comment: i have to warn you, we're well beyond my skill level here.  with that said.  you've confirmed you are crashing - is looks like mso.dll can have a hand in it.  this is a word plugin, so of it were me, i would uncheck the office reference and try again. if that didn't work, i would continue removing references that were not being used as part of  the project.  and i would also cross my fingers.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've removed all references that I could except for Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects x.x Library.and the issue still happens.

Comment: tell me to have a good explanation for this.  it mentioned it in my second post, different environment.....    why does your crash log have a different path than your project?  same file name, different locations and different users. 
 C:\Users\pasca\OneDrive\Desktop\ai\ai2  and your project shows data source=C:\Users\bissonp\Desktop\ai\ai2  .... i may be profoundly oblivious because i expect a crash or an error in that situation

Comment: Fixed the path again and changed both the db and excel file to the c drive and still persists.